# Problemas de validación de un TextBox usando C# y Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estoy desarrollando un formulario de **ASP.Net 2.0** con **C#** y tengo una duda con respecto a las validaciones.

Por ejemplo si valido un `TextBox` mediante Javascript en el TextBox le pongo `onkeypress="return event(e)"`, pero si entro al formulario y borro ese método `onkeypress` puede ingresar cualquier cosa y evitar la validación.

Me recomendaron que coloque `onblur="verif(this)"` pero esto de acá si lo borran no funcionará igual, ¿o me equivoco?

Me gustaría saber qué tipo de validación puedo usar para que no pueda ser editada o vulnerada como por ejemplo, desde el "inspector de elementos".

Comment: Saludos VikDC, tu pregunta tiene un gran % para ser cerrada debido a estar basada en opiniones/recomendaciones. Siempre hay que hacer doble verificación: en el lado del cliente y en el lado del servidor.

Comment: Pues puedes validar igual al momento de enviar los datos, cuando den click en el botón de envió puedes verificar que todos los campos cumplan las reglas de cada uno. Puedes hacerlo con Jquery para mayor comodidad.

Comment: te recomiendo que valides mediante anotaciones en tu modelo que es la mejor vía.

Comment: ¿Usas WebForms o MVC? ¿qué tipo de validaciones deseas implementar? ¿Puedes poner el código del `TextBox` y el código Javascript? Esto es para saber qué es lo que estas validando y poder darte una solución a tu problema. Mientras tanto tu pregunta puede ser cerrada ya que es demasiado amplia y/o se puede basar en opiniones.